# Arduino, check chars inside a byte array

Tags: c++, arduino

I am coding for a project where I update the time shown in an LCD 16x2 screen using commands from the serial port.
The command I am using to update the time is {I,A, H,H,M,M,F}, where it means that its initiating, A is for Add, HH and MM is hours and minutes to update to and F is for finish.

I created a global byte array to hold this input:

`byte bufferEntrada[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`

The problem: I need to check for possible letters inside the command and i don't know how.

Example: `IA1245F` is a valid command, but `IA12C5F` is a invalid one.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is each index an actual byte or a character? 0xB is different than "B"

Comment: They are being read as a byte.

Comment: To elaborate more, i defined the bufferEntry[16] variable as a byte and im using the serial interrupt method to get the input using the serialEvent function:
`void serialEvent()
{
    unsigned int i;
    if (!flagSerial)
    {
        bufferTamanho = Serial.available();
        for (i = 0; i < bufferTamanho; i++)
        {
            bufferEntrada[i] = Serial.read();
        }

        flagSerial = HIGH;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are sending **characters,** not bytes.  Although this is only a subtle difference, to your project it will make some difference.

You are sending ASCII characters. This means *the character* '0' can be represented as the decimal value 48.  If you look at an ASCII table you can see that *the characters* '0' to '9' have values 48 to 57, inclusive. These are the values you need to accept as integer digits.

```
if (aChar >= 48 && aChar <= 57) { ... } else { /* not a number */ }
```

In C, this can be made more readable:

```
if (aChar >= '0' && aChar <= '9') { ... } else { /* not a number */ }
```

or, by using the [isdigit()](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isdigit) standard function

```
if (isdigit(aChar)) { ... } else { /* not a number */ }
```

Note: On Arduino, the corresponding function is [isDigit()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/characters/isdigit/)

Answer (score -1):

Well, it turns out that im stupid, each character reads out as a decimal number referring to it in the ASCII table, so to check if there is any character there i only need to run a for loop checking if there is any value inside the byte array that is > 10.

Comment: I don't see how that will work since the ASCII code for the zero digit is 48 which is greater than ten.

Comment: If you are using ASCII characters then you need a different range